# SQL Server column as a parameter when the column is datetime type

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I want to use .net/C# to develop a web application. I have a SQL Server stored procedure and I want to pass dynamic datetime parameter.

When I use `exec(@sql)` here is the stored procedure with parameter I get :

> Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

I even tried passing some actual values (see below) and also tried debug in SQL Server, it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[production_tb_WorkshopDailyReports_INSERT]
    @intDepartmentID int,
    @intReportUserID int,
    @intProductionLineID int,
    @intBatchID int,
    @intVINID int,
    @columnname nvarchar(255),
    @dtOnlineTime datetime,
    @strRemark nvarchar(50),
    @intCreateUserID int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @column nvarchar(255)
    declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
    declare @intID int

    set @columnname = 'dtOnlineTimeChassis'
    set @column = @columnname
    set @intDepartmentID = 1
    set @intReportUserID = 1
    set @intProductionLineID = 1
    set @intBatchID = 1
    set @intVINID = 1
    set @dtOnlineTime = '2016-04-26 10:00:00pm'
    set @strRemark = 'remark information'
    set @intCreateUserID = 1
    set @sql = 'Insert Into production_tb_WorkshopDailyReports (intDepartmentID, intReportUserID, intProductionLineID, intBatchID, intVINID,' + @column + ', strRemark, intCreateUserID) values ' + '(' + cast(@intDepartmentID as nvarchar(20)) + ',' + cast(@intReportUserID as nvarchar(20)) + ',' + cast(@intProductionLineID as nvarchar(20)) + ',' + cast(@intBatchID as nvarchar(20)) + ',' + cast(@intVINID as nvarchar(20)) + ',' + @dtOnlineTime + ',' + @strRemark + ',' + cast(@intCreateUserID as nvarchar(20)) + ')'
        (@intReportUserID as nvarchar(20))+','+cast(@intProductionLineID as nvarchar(20))+','+cast(@intBatchID as nvarchar(20))+','+cast(@intVINID as nvarchar(20))+','+''+','+cast(@intCreateUserID as nvarchar(20))+')'

    exec(@sql)
End
```

Comment: Please have read on sql [CONVERT() fucntion](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) which would help you convert `string` to `datetime` without having to stick a single date format.

Comment: why do you want to use exec? can't you just use insert statement directly? It would avoid you formatting the query with commas and everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ ',''' + convert(varchar(26), @dtOnlineTime, 121) + ''',''' + @strRemark + ''',' +
```

1. Use CONVERT to convert the date value into a string.
2. Wrap dates and string values in quotes.

Comment: add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess all this:

```
set @columnname = 'dtOnlineTimeChassis'
set @column = @columnname
set @intDepartmentID = 1
set @intReportUserID = 1
set @intProductionLineID = 1
set @intBatchID = 1
set @intVINID = 1
set @dtOnlineTime = '2016-04-26 10:00:00pm'
set @strRemark = 'remark information'
set @intCreateUserID = 1
```

Is just for testing the SP, other time there will be something different in `@columnname` variable. If this statement is false then I suggest using simple `INSERT` instead of dynamic SQL.

At **first** change this:

```
',' + @dtOnlineTime + ',' + @strRemark + ','
```

To this:

```
 ',''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50),@dtOnlineTime,120)+''',''' + @strRemark + ''','
```

I suggest using `120` date style (ODBC canonical `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)`, for more info read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)) and you must put datetime variable and variable with some remark into `''`.

**Second** remove or comment this part (next string after `set @sql = ...`):

```
(@intReportUserID as nvarchar(20))+','+cast(@intProductionLineID as nvarchar(20))+','+cast(@intBatchID as nvarchar(20))+','+cast(@intVINID as nvarchar(20))+','+''+','+cast(@intCreateUserID as nvarchar(20))+')'
```

After `PRINT`ing your query you will see something like this:

```
Insert Into production_tb_WorkshopDailyReports (intDepartmentID, intReportUserID, intProductionLineID, intBatchID, intVINID,dtOnlineTimeChassis, strRemark, intCreateUserID) values 
(1,1,1,1,1,'2016-04-26 22:00:00','remark information',1)
```

Try to execute it.